# What is markathe? And why does King Vali calls Hanuman a markathe?

Tags: hanuman, vali

What is *markathe*? And why does King Vali calls Hanuman a *markathe*?

Comment: Markat is monkey in sanskrit

Comment: It will enhance your question to provide the quotation where Vali calls Hanuman "markathe".

Comment: As said by @moonstar2001, quote  Verse from Valmiki Ramayana as we will know context of word "Markathe".

Comment: I think you are asking this question after watching a TV show or a movie. AFAIK there are no direct conversations between Vali and Hanuman in the Valmiki Ramayana.

Answer (score 2):

Vaali calls Hanuman by the name Markata because in Sanskrit मर्कट​(Markata) denotes a Monkey/Ape which is similar to the appearance of Vanara.

[Source](http://sanskritdictionary.com/marka%E1%B9%ADa/172022/1)